# ostream for X, then generate for optional<X>, unique_ptr<X>, shared_ptr<X>, possibly variant<X, Z> or vector<X>

Tags: c++, iostream

Given a type `X` which should be printed I naturally implement
 `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x);`

If I want to avoid repeating the work for various wrappers like `std::optional<X>`, `std::unique_ptr<X>`, `std::shared_ptr<X>` etc. what are my options? Are there libraries which implement this already? Given these keywords something like this is terribly hard to search for, the closed I could find was the [Compile Time Type Information](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti) library, something I'd probably use to enhance the `optional` and `vector` outputs, but I want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: All the types you mentioned would need a different `operator<<`, since they might not have a value (you'd want to print something different/nothing for empty smart pointers and optionals).

Comment: Yes, they would check for "empty", then just output "{}"  or otherwise dereference the value and call the implemented operator and maybe add "uq{X}" - but that logic only needs to be written once for each wrapping type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the basic idea is that you add a templated `operator<<` that would SFINAE away based on the return type of `operator*` of the object it gets passed. Something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Expected>
using deref_to = std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>, Expected>;

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<deref_to<T, X>::value>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T &foo) {
    if(!foo)
        os << "{}";
    else
        os << *foo;
    return os;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WDwW_w), this even works for raw pointers. Doesn't cover `variant` or `vector`, although that shouldn't be too difficult to add as well.

To handle `std::variant`, `std::tuple`, and `std::pair` you would probably do the same, just with `std::get<X>` instead of `operator*`.

Comment: Though that exactly does not compile (X/Expected is undefined), I now use the explicit specializations (Filler because otherwise the templates are seen as duplicates)...

Comment: `template <typename T, typename U = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_same_v<T, std::unique_ptr<U>> >, typename Filler1 = char>`

Comment: `template <typename T, typename O = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_same_v<T, std::optional<O>>>, typename Filler1 = char, typename Filler2 = char>`

Comment: Look at the live demo, modulo copy paste errors it compiles exactly as posted. What error do you get?

Comment: Just tested whether the `operator<<` template is too greedy, doesn't seem like it.

Comment: The `deref_to<T, Foo>` -- i.e. specifying the wrapped value in the template which is supposed to be generic -- defeats the purpose, then `std::optional<Bar>` won't work.

Comment: Of course you need to add that template for every type you want, it's just generic in the container/pointer type. Otherwise it would be way too greedy and match things you don't want.